# Acknowledge from JAX-RS client

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I expose some JAX-RS (Resteasy) web services to a remote client.

One in particular is a service like "give me all news since the last time I asked you"; on the server I do my queries and all, and if everything went fine I update a property on the client which tells me future requests will start from that date.

The problem here is that if something goes wrong while returning the answer I could already have updated the "lastTime" property and so the client could find itself in the situation of never receiving part of the data.

What would be a good way of adding some kind of "acknowledge" from the client? Something that tells me that it received and correctly processd all the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your concept is wrong: Server should be stateless, while client should know what data he is interested in.
For example the client can use [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) header to get the information starting the date in the header. If server has no new, it should return 304 (Not Modified) code.

Comment: thanks for the idea, I'm quite new to REST and still have to learn a lot; we had a slightly different idea, but I think we can implement it such context